# Better runtime error in C++ for vectors and address boundary error

Tags: c++, arrays, gcc, vector, runtime-error

In Python, when we access an index out of the array range we get an error output that gives the exact location in the code that had this error:

```py
array = []
index =  0
array[index]
```

```bash
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Untitled-1 in <cell line: 3>()
      1 array = []
      2 index =  0
----> 3 array[index]

IndexError: list index out of range
```

But a code like this in C++ only gives us a generic address boundary error in both GCC and Clang compiler:

```cpp
#include <vector>

int main(int argc, const char **argv) {
  std::vector<int> array{};
  int index = 0;
  int value = array[index];

  return 0;
}
```

Is there a way to have better runtime errors with more detail in C++??

Comment: `int value = array.at(index);` will throw an exception. See the example in the documentation: [https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/at](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/at)

Comment: And why does `[]` not have to tell you that you screwed up? Because the test to see if you screwed up would take time. And you'd always have to put up with the test and loss of time even when you didn't screw up. That's not efficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> only give us a generic Address boundary error

No, it isn't even guaranteed to do that. Accessing out-of-bounds with `[]` causes *undefined behavior* in C++. If it happens you loose any guarantee on the program's behavior. It may fail with some kind of error, but it might also just continue running producing wrong output or do anything else. This is a very important difference from Python that must be understood. In C++ if you violate language rules or preconditions of library functions there is no guarantee that the compiler or the program will tell you about it. It will just not behave as expected in many cases.

To figure out where such an error comes from you usually run your program under a debugger which will tell you the line that e.g. a segmentation fault (if one happened) occurred and allows you to step through the code.

You can guarantee that indexing a `std::vector` out-of-bounds will generate an error message by using its `.at` member function instead of indexing with brackets. If the index is then out-of-bounds an exception will be thrown which you can catch or let propagate out of `main` to terminate the program with some error message. However, the exception doesn't typically carry information about the point at which it was thrown. Again you'll need to run under a debugger to get that information.

Depending on your compiler and platform, if you keep using `[]`, you may also be able to compile your program with a sanitizer enabled which will print a diagnostic including source lines when such an out-of-bounds access occurs. For example GCC and Clang have the address sanitizer which can be enabled with `-fsanitize=address` at compile-time. The option `-g` should be added as well to generate debug symbols that will be used in the sanitizer output to reference the source locations.

Comment: That `[]` is called the subscript operator.